# How can I attach a file from SharePoint document library to an item in a SharePoint list (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

In my current project I have encountered an interesting problem. I am trying to attach multiple files (pdf's, doc's etc. not only text files) to my SharePoint List, getting them from a document library. Problem is, when I use methods like get_web(), get_lists() etc. ending at get_file() from my current SP.ListItem, the type of file is SP.File (which is pretty obvious). In search for a solution I found this kind of method that uses SPServices:

http://www.bjw.co.nz/developer/sharepoint-2010/1188-spservices-addattachment-jquery-example

Here is the code:

```
    function handleFileChange(listName,itemId,files){
    var filereader = {},
        file = {},
        i=0;

    //loop over each file selected
    for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        file = files[i];            

        filereader = new FileReader();          
        filereader.filename = file.name;

        filereader.onload = function() {                
            var data = this.result,                     
                n=data.indexOf(";base64,") + 8; 

            //removing the first part of the dataurl give us the base64 bytes we need to feed to sharepoint
            data= data.substring(n);

            $().SPServices({
                operation: "AddAttachment",                 
                listName: listName,
                asynch: false,
                listItemID:itemId,
                fileName: this.filename,
                attachment: data,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {    
                    console.log('attachment upload complete',xData,status); 
                }
            });                 
        };

        filereader.onabort = function() {
            alert("The upload was aborted.");
        };

        filereader.onerror = function() {
            alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
        };              

        //fire the onload function giving it the dataurl
        filereader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    }
};
```

To use this solution I need to have an object of type File, not SP.File. My question is, how  can I get the actual file from a SharePoint document library to complete my task? I couldn't find an answer anywhere, so even the smallest hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is how to proceed (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370943/retrieving-binary-file-content-using-javascript-base64-encode-it-and-reverse-de):

```
// get the remote file binary content
function getBinary(file, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xhr.open("GET", file, true);
  xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined")
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if(xhr.status == 200) {
        callback(xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        console.log("Cannot find the remote file")
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
}

// convert the file content to a Base64 string
function base64Encode(str) {
  var CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var out = "", i = 0, len = str.length, c1, c2, c3;
  while (i < len) {
    c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
    if (i == len) {
      out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
      out += CHARS.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
      out += "==";
      break;
    }
    c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    if (i == len) {
      out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
      out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
      out += CHARS.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
      out += "=";
      break;
    }
    c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
    out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
    out += CHARS.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
    out += CHARS.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
  }
  return out;
}

getBinary('http://your.site.com/879258.jpeg', function(binary) {
  var data = base64Encode(binary);
  // add the Base64 string version of the remote file to the list item
  $().SPServices({
    webURL: "http://your.site.com/",
    operation: "AddAttachment",                 
    listName: "List 1",
    async: true,
    listItemID: 315,
    fileName: "879258.jpg",
    attachment: data,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {    
      console.log('attachment upload complete',xData,status); 
    }
  });
})
```

I tried it and it worked!

Comment: in IE it is failing at below line, as IE doesn't have overrideMimeType method.
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined") the same thing how can we work with IE, Your help is appreciated. Regards,
Bishnu-